# Prevent a user from pressing back, reload or close button

Tags: php, javascript, html

How to implement a function that prevents the user from using back, reload and close button of the browser? I mean that even if the user presses the reload, back or close button, those buttons do not work.

I saw similar question on stackoverflow but didn't find any relevant answer.

I want to achieve this because my laptop has some problem and these buttons work automatically sometimes which interrupt my work.

Comment: That would be very annoying for the user. I certainly wouldn't revisit a web site that did that!

Comment: what and why are you trying to achieve this ?

Comment: It can be useful for online transactions. However, I want to achieve this for my simplicity; my laptop has some problem and these buttons work automatically sometimes.

Comment: @k_programmer See my answer that is getting down-voted. It will get past the user pressing back, and reload won't matter. There is nothing you can do to get past close though. Users *may* dislike it, but it will do a good part of what you want.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? There are more and more reactions like this, as soon as someone wants to add this kind of constraints or "possibilities" to a web app. But you seem to forget that a browser is not only meant for "regular websites" but also for all kinds of applications, for example fullscreen touchscreen apps or professionnal/in-house apps that might require such settings. Another example is auto-printing documents, and there are plenty others like this. Why not just think of solutions to the guy's requirement?

Comment: @Fluffeh - Ya, I saw your answer. It can help a bit with the back button. But please help if you have got any idea about refresh and close button.

Comment: @darma - Thanks for support. Well, I do not die for upvotes and all; I don't have to do anything with these all. What I can add to my knowledge, that's all I want. I have noticed people downvote the questions they don't have the answer of.

Comment: @darma The down votes are because people don't like being forced to do *anything*. This sort of action on a website is *annoying* and the folks that hang out here *hate* it when websites do this sort of stuff. Hence the downvotes.

Comment: @Fluffeh - The upvotes and downvotes criteria is whether the question shows some research work or not. It's not for annoyance level.

Comment: @k_programmer It may have helped your cause if you had explained the context in which you wanted to use this. Before your edit it read as if you were wanting to prevent users from leaving your web site, not trying to solve a problem on your own laptop. Which is it?

Comment: @vascowhite - Both. I want to use for my laptop now; and it can be used for some purpose someday. Nothing is there in the world that is not useful.

Comment: @Fluffeh - as i said, not only "websites" run on a browser, i think that's a narrow point of view, as more and more kinds of apps happen in a browser.

Comment: @darma Yes, I think it is an question/answer that can be used or abused. That will be up to the developer of the page.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot, you have no authority to do so at the client computer.

Comment: You don't have the authority to do all of it - but there are ways around some of it. It *can* be annoying for the user, but some of it can be done.

Answer (score 4):

Use a javascript redirect page - though these are annoying to the user.

Say you have a form, use PHP `header()` to redirect to a page that contains a javascript `meta-refresh` looks like (`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'">`) which forces the user to a new page. When they hit back, they will hit that page and be forced forward again.

Edit: You *cannot* do anything about a close - but if you use this to redirect to a page that doesn't process anything like form information, then the user hitting refresh will not matter. They are on a static page anyhow.

Edit 2: I think it is amusing that when we use a PHP `header()` to redirect the user away from processing a payment transaction twice by accident, it is considered a good thing - but when a question like this comes up, everyone assumes the worst that someone is hijacking a webpage with horrible ads or spamming up some bollocks or other (and therefore the downvotes).

Comment: 1. very annoying. 2. the user will just click back twice

Comment: Sorry, I had to downvote this just because of the annoyance factor of your solution.

Comment: @Petra If the content is set to `0` which means instant, they have to go into their history to skip past it rather than pressing back, double clicking the back button will still force the user to the next page.

Comment: @vascowhite Yes, it is annoying, hence I put it in the original answer - but this *is* a way to accomplish what the poster is asking for. You shouldn't downvote an answer because you don't like it. You should upvote it for creative use of functions and add a comment saying that it is annoying - which I said in the original answer right off the bat.

Comment: @Fluffeh +1 for interesting solution. By the way, it will make application awful but it's not your fault, of course. :)

Comment: Actually my down votes are mine to use as I see fit, as are my up votes. Not liking an answer is a perfectly valid reason for down voting it regardless of how creative the author thinks it is. There arent many valid reasons for wanting to prevent users leaving your site and I don't like the fact that this behaviour is encouraged by providing a solution.

Comment: @vascowhite I guess I take that comment back. You can and should use your votes to show your pleasure/displeasure at an answer and how it might interact with your browser. I still stand by the fact that this *will* do much of what the poster wants to do. Annoying yes, would I use it? Perhaps in the right conditions, but more likely I would find a way to get past having to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not implementable with javascript. There are however browsers that support a kind of "kiosk mode" that does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery-hashchange](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange) plugin to detect the back button click and show an alert to the user. However, you can't completely control the browser actions as you suggested. Afterall it's his computer eh !

Answer (score 1):

That's maximum possible thing you cah do..

```
function PreventClosing() {
    if ( /Firefox[\/\s](\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent) && new Number(RegExp.$1) >= 4) {
        alert("Warning - may lost data.");
    }
    return "Warning - may lost data.";
}
window.onbeforeunload = PreventClosing;
```

Comment: Note: This only works on chrome, ie and firefox.

Comment: Thanks. At least something better than nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, which is a good thing because otherwise websites could do some pretty unethical things.

The closest you can come to this is using the onbeforeunload event, which will prompt the user if they want to leave or not.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can't.

Back in a day there was various ways to "brake" back button (by clearing history for example, but I'm not sure it those work anymore.

You can't however, directly mess with reload and/or close button, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this because browser's setting is manged by each browser at client side.and we can change browser settings with our web script.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the values in a session and reload them each time he revisits the same page. You can create some kind of a redirection to redirect to the same page.

PLEASE NOTE BY DOING SO U WILL BE ANNOYING, WHAT WE DO WITH ANNOYING WEBSITE => WE NEVER VISIT THEM AGAIN.